# Does jedis cannot get connection from slave node?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

When I was looking at the jedis source code, I found

`connection = connectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisClusterCRC16.getSlot(key));`

The jedispool corresponding to the slot in the cache is the master node information, so all client connections are connected to the master node when no connection exception occurs. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

For redis cluster, yes. And it's not relevant with jedis, every redis cluster client works this way.